# Download image from JSON

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I have image url in Json in  [img_url]  field.

I need to download it in ParseandDisplay method

ParseAndDisplay :

```
private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue json)
        {


            //ImageButton product = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.vugor);
            TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttittle);
            TextView price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
            TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.weight);
            productname.Click += delegate
            {
            var intent485 = new Intent(this, typeof(GoryachieRolli1));
                StartActivity(intent485);
            };
            JsonValue firstitem = json[1];
            //Console.Out.WriteLine(firstitem["post_title"].ToString());
            productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
            price.Text = firstitem["price"] + " грн";
            weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";


        }
```

How I download images now:

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl1(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }
```

I need to make downloading and displaying in parse and display

Comment: simply add a call to GetImageBitmapFromUrl1() in your other method?

Comment: are you using parse.com, or any other webservice for url

Comment: Yes, like this @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a call to your GetImageBitmapFromUrl1() method

```
productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
price.Text = firstitem["price"] + " грн";
weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";

Bitmap productImage = GetImageBitmapFromUrl1(firstitem["img_url"]);
```